# how can I save child object record from related list of parent object on visualforce page

Tags: controller, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to save opportunity record dynamically from a related list of Account object on visualforce page. For this:

- I have created a VF page in which I have used page block table.
- And when I click on add row then a new row is created on table but when I save opportunity then  AccountName field shows blank on the table(related list) and that opportunity record doesn't save in particular Account.

I am not getting the actual problem because when I System debug then Account and opplist isn't showing anything on saveopp(). I think Accountid is not going into opportunity's lookup field.

It would be really grateful for me if you people help me to solve this 
   problem. Thanks for your kind help :)

```
**VF Page:-**
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="taskDemo">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="" id="pb1" >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Assign" columns="2">
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.AccountNumber}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Website}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="updateRecord" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppList}" var="op">
        <apex:column headerValue="OpportunityName"> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!op.Name}">
        </apex:inputField>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="AccountName">
        <apex:inputField value="{!op.Account.Name}"></apex:inputField>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
        <apex:inputField value="{!op.Amount}">
        </apex:inputField>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="StageName">
        <apex:inputField value="{!op.StageName}">
        </apex:inputField>
        </apex:column>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:commandButton value="saveopp" action="{!saveopp}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="AddRow" action="{!addRow}" rerender="pb1"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

**Controller:-**
public class taskDemo {
 public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
 public List<Opportunity> oppList{get; set;}
 public Account a{get; set;}
 public String accId{get;set;}

public taskDemo(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    a = new Account();
    accId = controller.getId();
    System.debug('accid is::'+accId);
    oppList = [Select id,Name,Account.Name,Amount,StageName,CloseDate from 
                 Opportunity where AccountId =: accId];
}

public void addRow(){
    oppList.add(new Opportunity());
    Opportunity ts=new Opportunity();
    ts.AccountId = accId;
    System.debug('addrow::'+ ts.AccountId);
}
public PageReference saveopp(){
    if(a.Name != null){
        insert a;
        system.debug('a record is='+a);
        List<Opportunity> con = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Opportunity os : oppList)
        {
            os.AccountId = accId;
            con.add(os);
            system.debug('os record is='+os);
        }
        if(con != null){
            upsert oppList;
            system.debug('opp record is='+oppList);
        }
    }
    return null;        

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out a couple of issues and changes required in your code:

1. The default save method for your account is redirecting to the standard page. We need to redirect to the visualforce page again if required.
2. The constructor is not well defined, as it is querying for all opportunities if account Id is not present.
3. In addRow(), you are adding a record to the opportunity list first and then initializing a new opportunity record, which is incorrect. Also, we can't display Account name before inserting the record. The ideal solution would be not to display account name again in opportunity list, as we have the information on top of the page. We can link the opportunity to account at the time of saving opportunities.
4. In saveopp(), you must upsert account.
5. Also close date is a mandatory field to save an opportunity. Hence we need to get the information from UI.

I have updated your code. Please go through it and let me know if you have any queries.

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="taskDemo">
        <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="" id="pb1" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Assign" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AccountNumber}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Website}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="updateRecord" action="{!upsertAccount}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppList}" var="op">
            <apex:column headerValue="OpportunityName"> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!op.Name}">
            </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>
            <!--<apex:column headerValue="AccountName">
            <apex:inputField value="{!op.Account.Name}"></apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>-->
            <apex:column headerValue="Close date">
                <apex:inputField value="{!op.CloseDate}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
            <apex:inputField value="{!op.Amount}">
            </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="StageName">
            <apex:inputField value="{!op.StageName}">
            </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:commandButton value="saveopp" action="{!saveopp}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="AddRow" action="{!addRow}" rerender="pb1"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Apex extension:

```
public class taskDemo {
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public List<Opportunity> oppList{get; set;}
    public Account account{get; set;}
    public String accId{get;set;}

    public taskDemo(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        try{
            account = new Account();
            account = (Account)controller.getRecord();
            if(account.Id != null){
                oppList = [Select id,Name,Account.Name,Amount,StageName,CloseDate from 
                         Opportunity where AccountId =: account.Id];
                system.debug('Opportunities '+ oppList.size());    
            }
            else{
                oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
            }    
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
        }

    }

    public void addRow(){
        oppList.add(new Opportunity());
    }

    public pageReference upsertAccount(){
        Pagereference pg = Page.taskDemoPage;//please update taskDemoPage with the name of your vf page.
        if(account.Name != null){
            upsert account;
            pg.getParameters().put('Id',account.Id);
            pg.setRedirect(true);
        }
        else{
            pg = null;
        }
        return pg;
    }

    public PageReference saveopp(){
        try{
            pageReference pg = Page.taskDemoPage;//please update taskDemoPage with the name of your vf page.
            if(account.Name != null){
                upsert account;
                pg.getParameters().put('Id',account.Id);
                List<Opportunity> con = new List<Opportunity>();

                for(Opportunity os : oppList)
                {   
                    os.AccountId = account.Id;
                    con.add(os);
                    system.debug('os record is='+os);
                }
                if(con != null){
                    upsert oppList;
                    system.debug('opp record is='+oppList);
                }
            }
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Shyam Nair now the code is working fine..like what I really want..but can you explain me the changes which u hv made..?

Comment: Thanks @Pang you have edited something..can you explain, please?

Comment: Hi @Swarnika, I made below changes"

Comment: Hi @Swarnika, if you go through my comments in answer, you should be able to follow it. Some minor changes were made on the VF page, like adding Close date field and removing Account name field from Opportunity list. I also wrote a custom method called upsertAccount() to upsert Account record and navigate to the same page. In the controller, I have modified the constructor to avoid any exceptions. Also, I am modifying the code again to handle exceptions and display error on VF page. Please check it after 10 mins. Do let me know for any further queries. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Shyam Nair now I got it.. :-)